# Using right form of the verbs in sentences

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between "**We are decided**" and "**We decide**".

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if "We are decided" is even grammatically correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***We are decided to go to the park*** means that you have already made the decision (in the past) to go to the park. And now you just go because you already made the decision.

***We decide to go to the park*** means that you are deciding now (in the present) to go to the park.

Comment: Thx Tomas, It would be great if you could clear me the differences between "We are decided" VS "We have decided"

Comment: @Prasanth ***We have decided*** means that in the recent past you made a decision. ***We are decided*** means that you have a clear goal for something. For example *We are decided to go to hell* means that you really want to go to hell, you know you want it, you decided for it.